# Need clarification to understand the Standard Field in Salesforce App

Tags: salesforce, force.com

I was creating the Recruitment App with Salesforce by going through the study material. I have a question. In the custom object, I saw that I have created a Standard field named "Position Title" and after that I have to create all other fields as "Custom Field & RelationShips". My question is -> Is it the case that Position title is the primary key/unique identified in this object? If that is the case, why the data type is Text(80)? I can have two records with same Position Title "Sr. Manager", right? In that case, my primary key/unique constraint violates.

I have attached the screenshot below:
[image]

I am new to salesforce. So please help me in understanding the system? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce always create by default a group of fields called 'Standard fields', such as Created date, Last modified Date or Owner. In that list you'll probably interested in two, Id what is the primary key/unique identifier and Name which is a Text(80) field that you can't modify (only define if it's going to be text or an autonumber).

So to answer your first question, **Name** is actually not unique nor you identifier, and unfortunately at the moment salesforce doesn't give an easy option to have this functionality, in order to achieve that you could write a trigger with that restriction or define the Name as an autonumber and add the position title as a custom field with the unique checkbox marked.

The only problem with that last implementation is that the Name field is a special one with some behavior associated with it and it might obscure some of this functionality. For example, it will be the field shown when adding a relation to that object or in case you add the field to a related list, it will include a link to the actual object, but it will show the autonumber instead of the position title what doesn't give much information about the related object.

Here's a link with other people asking for the [same idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqCTAA0).